# Windows cmd command for stripping versions from filenames?

Tags: powershell, batch-rename

Need Windows cmd command to rename files to names without version numbers, e.g.:

```
  filename.exa.1     =>    filename.exa
filename_a.exb.23    =>  filename_a.exb
filename_b.exc.4567  =>  filename_b.exc
```

Filenames are variable in number of characters, and the primary extension is always 3 characters.

I once had a Solaris script "stripv" to accomplish this.  I could enter "stripv *" in a directory and get a nice clean set of non-versioned files.  If the command would result in duplicate filenames because multiple versions exist, then it would just skip the operation altogether.

TIA

Comment: You may want to add `powershell` to your tags

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do it in CMD, but here is some Powershell that would work for you:

```
# Quick way to get an array of filenames. You could also create a proper array,
# or read each line into an array from a file.
$filepaths = @"
C:\full\path\to\filename.exa.1
C:\full\path\to\filename_a.exb.23
\\server\share\path\to\filename_b.exc.4567
"@ -Split "`n"

# For each path in $filepaths
$filepaths | Foreach-Object {
  $path = $_

  # Split-Path -Leaf gets only the filename
  # -Replace expression just means to match on the ".number" at the end of the 
  # filename and replace it with an empty string (effectively removing it)
  $newFilename = ( Split-Path -Leaf $path ) -Replace '\.\d+$', ''

  # Warning output
  Write-Warning "Renaming '${path}' to '${newFilename}'"

  # Rename the file to the new name
  Rename-Item -Path $path -NewName $newFilename
}
```

Basically, this code creates an array of full paths to files. For each path, it strips the filename from the full path and replaces the `.number` pattern at the end with nothing, which removes it from the filename. Now that we have the new filename, we use `Rename-Item` to rename the file to the new name.

Answer (score 0):

Supply the folder name to this script block's `$Folder` variable, and it will enumerate the items within that folder, locate the last `'.'` character within the file name, and rename it as everything prior to the `'.'`.

E.g.: `Filename.123.wrcrw.txt.123` would be renamed as `Filename.123.wrcrw.txt` or in your case, your files would lose the extraneous characters from the final `'.'` onwards. If the new name for the file already exists, it will write a warning stating that it could not rename the file, and continue on without trying.

```
$Folder = "C:\ProgramData\Temp"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder | Foreach {

    $NewName = $_.Name.Substring(0,$_.Name.LastIndexOf('.'))

        IF (!(Test-Path $Folder\$NewName))
        {
            Rename-Item $Folder\$_ -NewName $NewName
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Warning "$($_.Name) cannot be renamed, $NewName already exists."
        }

}
```

This should effectively mimic the behaviour you described for `stripv *`. This could easily be turned into a function with name `stripv` and added to your PowerShell profile to make it available at the command-line interactively and used in the same way as your Solaris script.